# Reshape tensor in custom order (PyTorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, reshape, tensor

I have the following tensor

```
t = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15, 16, 17])
```

I want to reshape it in the following way:

```
t_reshape = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14], 
                          [3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]])
```

Are there ways to efficiently reshape tensors in that fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by reshaping, transposing and reshaping back:

```
>>> t.reshape(3,2,-1).transpose(0,1).reshape(2,-1)
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8, 12, 13, 14],
        [ 3,  4,  5,  9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]])
```